# Where does PHP save temporary files during uploading?

Tags: php

I am using XAMPP on Windows. By printing `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`, it seems that the temporary file was saved at C:\xampp\tmp\phpABCD.tmp. But I cannot see it on the filesystem of the server. However, the file can be moved or copied via `move_uploaded_file()`, `rename()`, or `copy()`. So where does PHP actually save temporary files during uploading?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It saves it at the path specified in `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`, but deletes it after the script is done executing. It's up to you to move the file elsewhere if you want to preserve it.

Comment: Thanks for "but deletes it after the script is done executing. "

Answer (score 24):

Its specified in  `upload_tmp_dir` in your php.ini file.  It is deleted by the system automatically after use.

Answer (score 12):

You can check where php is currently saving your temp `files $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` by printing

```
    sys_get_temp_dir()
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `move_uploaded_file(file, path)`, specify the file and the path where you want to store the file.

A copy of that file is created and gets stored.

Answer (score 4):

php stores all temporary files, that includes uploaded files, in the temporary files directory as specified in the php.ini. Note that for uploads, those files might be removed as soon as the script the file was uploaded to was terminated (so unless you delay that script, you probably won't see the uploaded file). Another reason might be that the file is simply hidden on the file system.

So if you want to see the file, you might want to make sure you see all hidden files in the explorer and delay the script as long as you need to find the file.

Answer (score 2):

from http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#93602, "...the uploaded file will inherit the permissions of the directory specified in the directive `upload_tmp_dir` of `php.ini`.  If this directive isn't set, the default of C:\Windows\Temp is used..."

Answer (score 0):

Note that the file is saved binary in `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`, so you may open it maybe with `file_get_contents` if it is an image or something like this...

Comment: What do you mean by "binary"? Would there be any other method to save a file?

Comment: @NicoHaase base64, other encoding methods that allow decryption, unpacking etc, by binary I meant that is not encoded in any way, ofcs that all data is binary.

Comment: base64 is not about decryption after all

Answer (score -1):

IF you are asking the file location then it depend on the setting of server. but if you are asking whether it saved first in local system  or in server. then answer is it save in temp folder in server.

Comment: This does not answer the given question. Have a look at the other answers, especially at the one the OP accepted